# string matching with interchangeable characters

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to do a simple string matching between two strings, a small string to a bigger string. The only catch is that I want to equate two characters in the small string to be the same. In particular if there is a character `'I'` or a character `'L'` in the smaller string, then I want it to be considered interchangeably.

For example let's say my small string is

```
s = 'AKIIMP'
```

and then the bigger string is:

```
b = 'MPKGEXAKILMP'
```

I want to write a function that will take the two strings and checks if the smaller one is in the big one. In this particular example even though the smaller string `s` is not a substring in `b` because there is no exact match, however in my case it should match with it because like I mentioned characters `'I'` and `'L'` would be used interchangeably and therefore the result should find a match.

Any idea of how I could proceed with this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
s.replace('I', 'L') in b.replace('I', 'L')
```

will evaluate to True in your example.

Comment: Very simple and elegant

Answer (score 3):

You could do it with [regular expressions](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/regex.html):

```
import re

s = 'AKIIMP'
b = 'MPKGEXAKILMP'

p = re.sub('[IL]', '[IL]', s)
if re.search(p, b):
    print(f'{s!r} is in {b!r}')
else:
    print('Not found')
```

This is not as elegant as [@Deepstop's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56638992/2988730), but it provides a bit more flexibility in terms of what characters you equate.